# Input not showing in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, google-chrome, websocket

I have been working on a simple WebSocket chat script, and have run into a few problems. My Javascript is pretty simple:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://109.74.195.222:8888', 'echo-protocol');
ws.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
    var msg = e.data;
    $('#chatlog').append("<br />" + msg);
});
$('#submit').click(function(){
    var message = $('#message').val();
    ws.send(message);  
});
```

as it my HTML:

```
<div id="chatlog"></div>
<input type="text" id="message">
<button type="submit" id="submit">Send message</button>
```

My server works, and as does the messages, when using it in Safari. Even on Chrome, messages appear when sent from another client, however the Input does not appear. I have tried inspecting it using Chrome developer tools, nothing. I have created a jsFiddle over at http://jsfiddle.net/xKLje/2/, and if you open it up in Chrome you will see not input, however other browsers have no issue. There are no errors (as far as I can tell) in the error console.

Comment: I have added the Node.js tag again, as that is what the server is running.

Comment: I've tried the jsFiddle with chrome and I see the input. Version: 31.0.1650.63 m

Comment: Really? [I don't](http://i.imgur.com/y7irxfb.png).

Comment: Ok, [I've just tried in Incognito](http://i.imgur.com/M6N3gwd.png) and it appears, so it must be an extension problem. Sorry for the stupid post in that case.

Comment: The extension blocking it was 4chan Plus, so I have no idea what was going on there...

Comment: is that a extension to avoid getting into 4chan? XD

Comment: Nope, in theory it's meant to add useful features to 4chan, but on further analysis it appears that it looks for all inputs with the `message` id, and then removes them... on every site...